# Formulae in Word Mail Merge

Tags: microsoft-word, email, mail-merge

I have a condo owners database to use as a data source in MS Word Merge to Email. I can separate the unit number to identify what tower, floor, and stack the unit is in. For example, 3802 is in the Ewa tower (all even numbers), 38 is the floor, and stack is 02. I would need to use a formula to determine if the unit number was even or odd, and the floor to determine if it was in a range of floors, say 32 to 42, and stack (vertical stack, ie: stacks 2,4,6).

Is this possible within a Word Mail-Merge to Email?  Or should I just add fields to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's really easy to maintain additional fields in your database (e.g. using a view or some such) then I would do it that way, partly because you then have all the necessary pieces of data however many different Mailmerge main documents you need.

You can use { = } fields to do the calculations and { IF } fields to insert different texts depending on the calculation results.

For example, if all your unit numbers are positive 4-digit numbers in a column in your data source called `unit`, you could use

```
{ =MOD({ MERGEFIELD unit },2) \#0 }
```

to determine if the unit has an odd or even number (the result will be `0` for even and `1` for odd)

NB, **all** the `{ }` have to be the special field code braces that you can insert on Windows Desktop Word using ctrl-F9, not the ordinary characters `{` and `}` that you can type via the keyboard.

You only need the `\#0` if you need to ensure that you get the result `0` rather than `0.0`

You could use

```
{ IF { =MOD({ MERGEFIELD unit },2 \#0 } = 0 "text if the unit number is even" "text iif the unit number is odd" }
```

to insert different texts depending on whether the unit is odd or even.

You could use

```
{ =INT({ MERGEFIELD unit }/100) }
```

to get the floor. If you always need the floor to be a two-digit number you could use

```
{ =INT({ MERGEFIELD unit }/100) \#00 }
```

You could use

```
{ ={ MERGEFIELD unit }-(INT({ MERGEFIELD unit }/100))*100 }
```

to get the stack. (MOD works up to MOD(,99) but not MOD(,100)

You can store intermediate results using SET fields, e.g.

```
{ SET unitx { MERGEFIELD unit } }
{ SET oddeven { =MOD(unitx,2) } }
{ SET floor { =INT(unitx/100) } }
{ SET stack { =unitx-(floor*100) } }
```

Then you can do things like

```
{ IF floor >= 32 "{ IF floor <= 42 "floor is 32 thru 42" "above 42" }" "below 32" }
```

(Pay attention to the spacing in IF comparisons, e.g. `floor >=32` doesn't work.)

If floor numbers can be negative, things can get a bit more complicated. There are usually several ways you can achieve the same results. It's probably better to start experimenting with these types of field code than try to cover all the different possible approaches.

Comment: Wow!  This is why I use SuperUser.com.  Thanks.  I got schooled and I really appreciate it.  Thank you so much.

Comment: It more than answers it.  I've just spent about 10 minutes trying to figure out how to flag it as the best answer.  I feel like an idiot.  Can you point me in the right direction?  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks.  And sorry I didn't notice it before.  So much to learn...